# SQL use return value of function as procedure parameter

Tags: sql, function, procedure

Let's define:

```
create table cities
(
    ID int identity,
    name varchar(50) unique
)


create function getID (@name varchar(50)) returns int
begin
    declare @id int
    select @id=ID from cities where name=@name
    return @id
end

create procedure addLine
    @cityID int
as begin
    ...
end
```

Is it possible to execute a procedure with value returned by function, as follows?

```
exec addLine getID('Warsaw')
exec addLine dbo.getID('Warsaw')
exec addLine (select dbo.getID('Warsaw'))
```

I tried above and it did not help.

Comment: How is it not working? Have you used a step-through debugger?

Comment: honestly, I have never use it so that I dont know how to do it, I will try to find that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft says that this is not possible. You can not pass result of a function to procedure as a parameter:

```
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
    { 
      ...
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
                           | [ DEFAULT ] 
                           }
        ]
      ...
    }
[;]
```

So, only constant values, variables and `DEFAULT` keyword are permitted.
2 possible ways of doing this are:

1: declare variable

```
declare @i int =  dbo.getID('Warsaw')
exec addLine @i
```

2: use dynamic query

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'exec addLine ' + CAST(dbo.getID('Warsaw') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
EXEC(@cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will "execute a procedure with value returned by function"

It just won't do it 'inline'

```
declare @id int
select @id = dbo.getID('Warsaw')
exec addLine @id
```